# cpp function to retrieve values of various datatype

Tags: c++, function, types, return-value

I want to write a cpp function something similar to this, where outVal should accept data of the corresponding type returned from the respective functions in each case.

```
void ReadFieldByType(char fieldType, string content, string& outStr, **unknown**& outVal){
unsigned int ifield;
char cField;
string sField;
double dField;
switch (fieldType)
                {
                case 'c':
                ReadChar(content, content, cField);
                outVal = cField;
                break;
                case 'd':
                ReadInteger(content, content, ifield);
                outVal = ifield;
                break;
                case 'f':
                ReadDouble(content, content, dField);
                outVal = dField;
                break;
                case 's':
                ReadString(content, content, sField);
                outVal = sField;
                break;
                default:
                break;
                }
                outStr = content;}
```

I don't know how to set datatype for outVal. Can this be improved or is there any other choice to accomplish this task?

Comment: >>> templates <<< or overloading

Comment: @LuchianGrigore How templates can help here? Type is in fieldType and i think determines in runtime.

Comment: I think this is not a good design. I would rather create a template method `ReadField<T>`.

Comment: Thank you for your sugesstions

Comment: What is the meaning of `content`?  And why is it passed twice to `ReadChar()` et al.?

Comment: content is a string of numbers and chars. I wanna read the number or char whatever may be and return the remaining string for further process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do it with templates and the [`typeid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) operator:

```
template<class T>
void ReadField(string content, string& outStr, T& outVal)
{
    if (typeid(T) == typeid(int))
        ReadInteger(content, content, outVal);
    else if (typeid(T) == typeid(char))
        ReadChar(content, content, outVal);
    else if (typeid(T) == typeid(double))
        ReadDouble(content, content, outVal);
    else if (typeid(T) == typeid(std::string))
        ReadString(content, content, outVal);

    outStr = content;
}
```

Although I have to admit that I don't like the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/variant.html).

In your case you would use something like:

```
typedef boost::variant<char, int double, std::string> out_t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use union, it allows to choose type of variable;

```
union
{
    unsigned int ifield;
    char cField;
    string sField;
    double dField;} outVal;
void ReadFieldByType(char fieldType, string content, string& outStr, **unknown**& outVal){

switch (fieldType)
                {
                case 'c':
                ReadChar(content, content, cField);
                outVal.cField = cField;
                break;
                case 'd':
                ReadInteger(content, content, ifield);
                outVal.ifield = ifield;
                break;
                case 'f':
                ReadDouble(content, content, dField);
                outVal.dField = dField;
                break;
                case 's':
                ReadString(content, content, sField);
                outVal.sField = sField;
                break;
                default:
                break;
                }
                outStr = content;}
```